# illegal characters in path for asp.net mvc

Tags: c#

I am new in asp.net mvc.

I am trying to create a web application but illegal character in path keeps on appearing on this line once I run the program:

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Students.ToList());
    }
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.  How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "illegal character in path keeps on appearing"?  What is the exact error you're seeing?  If there's a stack trace, what is it?  What relevant runtime values are there when the error happens?

Answer (score 0):

This could be illegal characters in the database connection string/login details, or the URL of the page, and not an MVC issue.

Check the back/forward slashes (single/multiple) are correctly formatted to connect to the server - spaces too.